# Start reading a text file from a particular line

Tags: java, io, text-files

Is a way to pen a text file, read a few lines, close it, re-open it and start reading from the line where you left off before? Or do you always have to start from the top?

Comment: Well, what if the file contents change between the time you close and re-open the file? Would the same line still be relevant to start reading from again?

Comment: I'm assuming that you can only append to the file.

Comment: You mean you're assuming that your code is the only possible code that will read/write to the file, and it will only append to it? If so, why not just keep the file open?

Comment: No, my code is not the only code to access the file.But it is a log file of sorts, so whoever's writing to it would presumably only be appending to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just start from the top each time. This is the simplest and possibly not much slower.  You can use a RandomAccessFile but you would have to wrap it with your own line reader (as well as place some check that the file hasn't changed in an incompatible manner)

Comment: Actually, seeking is WAY faster than reading whole file to the desired place. So RandomAccessFile is a way to go. Also, the wrapper for it is not that hard to write or even find in the internet.

Comment: Ok, I've just checked the API and noticed that RandomAccessFile already has `String readLine()` implemented.

Comment: You can read at a rate of 100 MB/second a file you just read. So re-reading 10 MB file takes about 100 ms. If you have a 10 GB text file it can make a real difference.

Comment: Its worth reading the comments for RandomAccessFile.readLine() as it doesn't do any character encoding. It assumes all data is ASCII.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand from the documentation of RandomAccessFile though: can you use this class to work with a regular text file?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! This is not going to be the fastest method, but it is going to work. And, by the way, the people who responded to your question by telling you that you should just start reprocessing from the beginning of the file TOTALLY missed the point of your question. There are an ample amount of reasons to want to return to where you left off.

Here is some code I wrote that allows you to store a counter value, and then iterate through the file until you re-reach the counter value... at which point the loop takes affect and process what is in the loop for the remaining lines.

Cheers!

```
//define input text file
def file = new File('C:\\inputtextfile.txt')
//define file for the last referenced counter
def CountFile = new File ('C:\\prime\\lastcount.txt')

//if the counter was null set it to zero
if (CountFile.eachLine({it}) == null){
CountFile.write('0')
}

//read the counter into a value
StartLine = CountFile.eachLine( {it} ) as long
//set the first line of the file
lineCount=0

file.eachLine { line  ->
if (lineCount >= StartLine){


//write the counter to a text file
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CountFile.write(lineCount.toString())
    lineCount++
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure every time you open a file, it starts you from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just save the line number externally and jump to / seek the desired position?